# Esta función no me pone el título de la página

Tags: php

```
function generare_header($titlu=''){

$head = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bucuresti'.$titlu = ''.'</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../webAzex/style/site.css">
</head>
<body> ';

echo $head;}







<?php 
require_once 'componente/header.php';
    require_once 'date/meniu.php';  
        require_once 'componente/footer.php';
    $titlu='Index';
    generare_header($titlu='Index');
        echo $meniu;

    ?>

<h1>Pagina de index</h1>
<?php echo $footer;?>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo la estás llamando y en qué contexto (desde dónde)? ¿Le estás pasando algo para que lo use mediante el parámetro `$titlu`?

Comment: @Nistor es lo mismo que iba a preguntar? Así es difícil adivinar el problema.

Comment: @Nistor y el código de este parámetro `$titlu=''`?

Comment: Hola Bienvenid@ al sitio Nistor!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio!. Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Al comienzo de nuestro **script**, nos crea el encabezado de nuestro documento **HTML** y coloca el titulo que queremos a la página:

```
<?
function hacer_encabezado($titulo) {
  $encabezado="<html><head>t<title>$titulo</title></head>";
  echo $encabezado;
}
?>
```

Esta función podría ser llamada al principio de todas nuestras páginas de la siguiente forma:

```
$titulo="Mi web";
hacer_encabezado($titulo);
```

[Aquí](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/312.php) Encontraras mas ejemplo de como se pasa el parametro por si no se lo estas pasando bien.

Comment: He intentado y no me muestra el Titulo de la pagina  tanto el de html como lo que esta almacendo en la variable <html><head>t<title>$titulo</title></head> el  link rel carga perfectamente.

Comment: Es decir no pudo ver esta linea  <title>Bucuresti '.$titlu.'</title>

Answer (score 0):

No lo estás realizando bien.

```
function generare_header($titlu=''){

$head = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bucuresti '.$titlu.'</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../webAzex/style/site.css">
</head>
<body> ';

echo $head;}
```

El error es ponerle de nuevo el `$titlu = ''`, esa variable ya está definida, por lo que te estará quitando el titulo que le estés pasando o bien directamente te petará.